# Sharepoint 404 error after renaming subsite

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-404

I renamed a Sharepoint site directory site from "Sites" to "Team Sites" and then back again. Now whenever I try to access it, or any of its subsites, I get the error

`HTTP/1.1 404 Connection: close Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2009 13:08:59 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6219`

I'd be quite happy just to delete the site and create a new one but it won't let me (using Sharepoint designer) as there are subsites. And I can't delete the subsites because I can't see them in any of the admin options!

Does anybody know how to fix this? Many thanks if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first tip would be to never, ever, ever use SharePoint Designer for anything other then editing page layouts, master pages, etc. It is useless piece of crpa and normally makes things worse (try checking files in and out using SPD and you'll eventually get into a mess with it).

As for your subsite - try going to the site manager page for the site:

> http://yoursite/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx

Replace the 'http' part with whatever your site collection's url is, but add the /_layouts/... bit after it. You should then see an explorer type view of all the sites. On the left, navigate to the subiste you have renamed, just to see that it still exists. If it's there, hover the mouse over the name of the site and you should see a dropdown menu appear. One of the options on that menu is 'Site Setting'. Click on that to see if it will take you to the site settings for the site.

If that fails, then look at using [stsadm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263508.aspx) to try and rename the website.