# Sharepoint 2010 404 Error after Renaming Subsite

Tags: sharepoint, iis, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

We are still in the process of rolling out SharePoint, but we’ve got the server up and running and the primary site is working.  We set it up as sharepoint.mydomain.com.  I then created a new site called ‘Help Center’ and it’s URL was sharepoint.mydomain.com/help_center.  After adding a bunch of content, and starting to plan to roll it out we decided to change the URL to sharepoint.crowholdings.com/help (just because we are picky like that).  I did this by going to the site (at the original URL), going to Site Settings>Title, Description, and Icon, and in the URL name box I changed ‘help_center’ to ‘help’ and clicked OK.  That’s when all hell broke loose.  I got an error, and unfortunately I did-not capture it before moving on so I don’t remember exactly what it said – but I noticed that in the address bar it was still showing the old URL (/help_center/) so I tried changing it to the new URL (/help/) but then I got a 404 error.  I tried IISReset, and even rebooted the server – but I still get a 404 error every time I try to access the page.  Back on my primary site, the URL on the Help Center tab has been updated to the new URL (sharepoint.mydomain.com/help/SitePages/Home.aspx), but when I click it I just get the 404 error.  I can’t access the site with the new URL or the old URL.

I can still see the site and all of it's assets in the site manager, but I still get the 404 error when I try to access any of the site settings from the menu (site settings, people and groups, advanced permissions, or general settings). If I try changing the URL in the address bar from the new name to the old name, i get a different error that just says 'file not found'.

I also tried using the stsadm commands (referenced here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263508.aspx), but I get the following errors:

- When I try using the NEW name, I get the error: The site
  sharepoint.mydomain.com/newsite could not be found in the Web
  application SPWebApplication Name=sharepoint.mydomain.com.
- When I try using the OLD name, I get the error: 0x80070002There is no Web named "/oldsite".

Any other suggetions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! ][Q][

Here's a similar post, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me: [Sharepoint 404 error after renaming subsite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673678/sharepoint-404-error-after-renaming-subsite/12358909#12358909)

Comment: I posted this info again on the SharePoint.StackExchange.com forum as-well - maybe someone there can help me. I appreciate all of your suggestions, please keep-em-coming... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45408/sharepoint-2010-404-error-after-renaming-subsite

Comment: Aha! I finally found a solution, although I'm still unsure what the problem was. I used SharePoint Manager 2010 [http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438] to change the 'ServerRelativeUrl' in the properties back to '/help_center' and now the site works again! I'm not even going to bother trying to change it back - don't feel like messing with it anymore...

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely odd. As you used another URL once - you only changed the sub site's name (+URL) and did not change host headers and the site collection the sub site resided in before?

You can use SharePoint Designer to make sure that your site is still in place - can you use SharePoint Designer? Does it throw an error when you try to connect it to `...<yoururl>.../help`, or do you have to use `.../help_site`?

What you did not mention, but should always be your first step: Check the ULS Logs. You can find them here:
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS`. A perfect tool to view them is the [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) from Microsoft. You most likely will find more information than just the 404.

Furthermore I would try to inspect the site (`SPWeb` to be clear) e.g. via PowerShell or via [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com). Check out the `SPWeb.AbsoluteUrl` and all other URL related properties and check whether anything seems odd. In Powershell you would get a site like so:

```
$help = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/help
$help | get-members
```

With `get-members` you will see all the methods and properties available to check out.

Your behavior definitely is not normal and you will need to do a bit more digging. I would start with the ULS logs.

Comment: In SharePoint Designer, I can connect to http://sharepoint.mydomain.com, and I can SEE the sub-site called 'Help Center' (it shows the URL /help/), but when I try to connect to it I get this: Server error: The URL "http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/help/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll" is not contained within a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site.

Comment: When I try to run the PowerShell cmdlets you provided, I can't get past the first line before I get this error (same error when I use the old and new URL):

Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url:
 http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/help.
At line:1 char:18
+ $help = get-spweb <<<<  http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/help
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:
   SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb

Comment: Thanks @moontear for the tip on checking out the ULS logs and the link to the ULS viewer.  Here's an excerpt from the ULS logs when I try to access the sub-site (there's more, but it won't let me post all the lines): w3wp.exe (0x2DDC) 0x03D8 SharePoint Foundation General 8e2s Medium Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002 5a423cca-765a-4b79-aed9-31a25f097429

Comment: Hmm that doesn't help me a great deal. You can also just call `Get-SPWeb` without parameters to see what sites exist (or `Get-SPSite` for that matter). Try to read through the ULS logs if anything helps solving your case.

Comment: 'get-spweb without parameters' gives me an error that I need to provide a full URL or spsite object. When I run `get-spweb http://sharepoint.mydomain.com` it just comes back with http://sharepoint.mydomain.com under URL. When I run get-spsite, I get a list that mainly contains root sites (we have a few for our AX/CRM environment), and then I do see http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/DMS which is another sub-site I created - but I do-not see the Help Center site listed.

Comment: I found this script on another thread (the one referenced at the bottom of my original post), and it returns a list that includes one titled 'Help Center' with the URL /help:  `$site = Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint.mydomain.com"
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) { 
$web | Select-Object -Property Title,Url | format-table -auto
}`

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's very late, but one of the reasons is that you may have a Virtual Directory in the IIS with the same name ("help").

Answer (score -2):

Powershell or SharePoint Designer might help

Powershell

Remove-SPSite -Identity "URL" -GradualDelete

SharePoint Designer, can it see the site in question?

Comment: I'm a bit scared to run the remove-spsite command, as that is not what I'm trying to do.  I want to keep the site and all of it's content, but as of now I can't access it.  I am able to see the site in SharePoint Designer, and in PowerShell, and both show the NEW URL - but I still can't access the site. SPD says Server error: The URL "http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/help/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll" is not contained within a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site.  Here's the output from PowerShell:  Title: Help Center; Url http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/help

Comment: Why would you suggest `Remove-SPSite`? The poster does not want to remove the site, but to get it to work with a new URL. As for Powershell and SharePoint Designer - how will they help?